# How to pass values to web service via Ajax

Tags: javascript, ajax, web-services

I'm trying to send some values to my web service on ajax call.

**html**

```
<button type="submit"  id="gen" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getval();">
```

**Javascript**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
function getval(){
  $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/aa/testService.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: {"name" :"abc",age="20"}
        success: function (response) {                    
            console.log(response);
        }
  });
}});
```

but my error log showing

```
line 38 "data: {"name" :"abc",age="20"}"  - Unexpected " :", expected one of: "}"
```

why is that?how to resolve this?

**Solution-update**

remove `data:object` and pass values through url `url: base_url+"/aa/testService.php?name='abc'"`

Answer (score 1):

You have a wrong syntax in the `data` property. Replace the `=` with `:` and add `,` after it.

```
data: {"name": "abc", age: "20"},
success: function (response) {
   console.log(response);
}
```

Comment: no luck `data: {"name" :"abc","age": "20"}"  - Unexpected " :", expected one of: "}`

Comment: Have you put `,` after that line?

Comment: yes now line is like this `data: {"name" :"abc","age": "20"},`

Comment: try without double quote as 
`data: {name : "abc", age : "20"}`

Comment: shouldn't make a difference, @NageshKatke

Comment: thanks for reply. i found the solution.if you are using GET method you can't pass `data : obj`.

Answer (score 0):

Please follow the solution below.

```
<button type="submit"  id="gen" class="btn btn-primary" onclick="getval();">


function getval(){

  $.ajax({
        url: base_url+"/aa/testService.php",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        type: "GET",
        data: JSON.stringfy({"name": "abc", "age": "20"})
        success: function (response) {                    
            console.log(response);
        }
  });

  return false;
}
```